# Calling Methods from one API is done but facing Not found error on second API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two Wep APIs. I have done CRUD operation using one eg. Customer. But when I built another Similar Web API and called a method It shows:

> {,…} Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   http://localhost:23995/Product/Insert'."
>
> MessageDetail: "No route providing a controller name was found to
>   match request URI '[[same link as above here]]'"

Here is my JS Calling Method:

```
$scope.Insert = function () {    

    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:23995/Product/Insert',
        data: JSON.stringify($scope.Product)
    }).then(function (response) {
        alert("chec");

    });
}
```

In Product Controller

```
// Insert 
[HttpPost]
[Route("{controller}/Insert")] 
public string Insert([FromBody] Product newProd) { 
    newProd.Insert(); 
    return newProd.DbResponse; 
}
```

In supplier Controller

```
// Insert 
[HttpPost] 
[Route("{controller}/Insert")] 
public string Insert([FromBody] Product newProd) { 
    newProd.Insert(); 
    return newProd.DbResponse; 
}
```

Comment: In Product Controller  
// Insert
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("{controller}/Insert")]
        public string Insert([FromBody] Product newProd)
        {
            newProd.Insert();
            return newProd.DbResponse;
        }



In supplier Controller  
// Insert
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("{controller}/Insert")]
        public string Insert([FromBody] Product newProd)
        {
            newProd.Insert();
            return newProd.DbResponse;
        }

Comment: you should use edit to improve your question and not the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have attribute routing enabled.

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#enable)

> To enable attribute routing, call `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` during
>   configuration. This extension method is defined in the
>   `System.Web.Http.HttpConfigurationExtensions` class.

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Other Web API configuration not shown.
        }
    }
}
```

and assuming that given the route you are getting the error on

```
http://localhost:23995/Product/Insert
```

Your product controller should look something like this.

```
[RoutePrefix("product")]
public class ProductController : ApiController {
    // ... other code removed for brevity

    // Insert 
    // eg: POST /product/insert
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("insert")] 
    public string Insert([FromBody] Product newProd) {...}
}
```

and your supplier controller would look very similar

```
[RoutePrefix("supplier")]
public class SupplierController : ApiController {
    // ... other code removed for brevity

    // Insert 
    // eg: POST /supplier/insert
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("insert")] 
    public string Insert([FromBody] Product newProd) {...}
}
```

you calling JavaScript should then be able to properly call the desired methods

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a controller named "ProductController" with a method named Insert?

Looks like that's all that is missing for you.

Comment: Thanks for posting answer, Yes I have ProductController and it has methods. I have two controllers ProductController and SupplierController my problem is due to
 // Insert
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("{controller}/InsertProduct")]
        public string Insert([FromBody] Product newProd)
        {
            newProd.Insert();
            return newProd.DbResponse;
        }